# turn off blur events and use 1 button to update fields

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I  have a website that manages accounts of agents. Fields are updating when blur event occurs, but i created one UPDATE button to update the fields by clicking on it. Now i want to disable those blur events and update fields by using one UPDATE button instead of updating fields one by one by blur events.
Sorry if this has a simple solution, I'm just new to scripting.

**index.php**

```
$(document).on('blur', '.username', function() {
  var id = $(this).data("id7");
  var username = $(this).text();
  edit_data(id, username, "username");
});

$(document).on('blur', '.password', function() {
  var id = $(this).data("id8");
  var password = $(this).text();
  edit_data(id, password, "password");
});


function edit_data(id, text, column_name) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "edit.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      id: id,
      text: text,
      column_name: column_name
    },
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {
      //animations and effects
      $('body, html').animate({
        scrollTop: 0
      }, 100);
      $("alert").delay(3200).fadeOut(300);
      document.getElementById("alert").style.visibility = "visible";
      document.getElementById("alert-cont").innerHTML = data;

    }
  });
}
$(document).on('click', '#update_btn', function() {

  ////CODE TO DISABLE BLUR EVENTS AND UPDATE .username and .password fields BY SINGLE CLICK
});
```

**anotherpage.php**
this is where the '.username' ,'.password' and '#update_btn' came from.

```
$output. = '
<tr class="datas">

  <td class="id" data-id10="'.$row[" id "].
'" <td class="username" data-id7="'.$row[" id "].
'" contenteditable>'.$row["username"]. '
  </td>
  <td class="password" data-id8="'.$row[" id "].
'" contenteditable>'.$row["password"]. '
  </td>

  <button type="button" name="up_btn" id="update_btn" data-id12="'.$row[" id "].
'" onclick="update()">UPDATE</button>
  </td>
</tr>
';
```

Comment: How about the deleting the code that attaches `blur` event

Comment: i think this code will be a problem edit_data(id, username, "username"); when deleted because it is the function to update the field data. What i want  is just disable blur events but execute them in the update button so the function edit_data(id, username, "username"); will be executed and update the data to the database